# Oracle's left join and where clauses errors

Tags: oracle, join

```
CREATE TABLE "ATABLE1"
  (
    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  );

CREATE TABLE "ATABLE2"
  (
    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  );

Insert into ATABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('A','1');
Insert into ATABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('B','2');

Insert into ATABLE2 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('A',null);
Insert into ATABLE2 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('A','1');
Insert into ATABLE2 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('A','2');

select ATABLE1.column1, count(ATABLE2.column1) 
    from ATABLE1 Left OUTER JOIN ATABLE2 on ATABLE1.column1 = atable2.column1
    GROUP BY ATABLE1.column1;

Result

COLUMN1              COUNT(ATABLE2.COLUMN1) 
-------------------- ---------------------- 
A                    3                      
B                    0
```

This works as expected. The thing is that I always want all rows from ATABLE1 to be shown and also apply some restrictions.

```
select ATABLE1.column1, count(ATABLE2.column1) 
    from ATABLE1 Left OUTER JOIN ATABLE2 on ATABLE1.column1 = atable2.column1
    where atable2.column2 = '1'
    GROUP BY ATABLE1.column1;


COLUMN1              COUNT(ATABLE2.COLUMN1) 
-------------------- ---------------------- 
A                    1
```

Why are not all columns from ATABLE1 being shown even with left join? How can I make them appear?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: +1, especially for the effort you have put into setting up the test objects

Comment: "Why are not *all columns* from ATABLE1 being shown even with left join?" - did you mean to say 'all rows'?

Comment: @JackDouglas yes, that would make more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add WHERE filters to the optional/outer table, then you change the query into an INNER JOIN. You need to add the condition into the join, or derived table, or CTE.

```
select ATABLE1.column1, count(ATABLE2.column1) 
    from ATABLE1 Left OUTER JOIN ATABLE2
         on ATABLE1.column1 = atable2.column1 AND atable2.column2 = '1'
    GROUP BY ATABLE1.column1;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why are not all columns from ATABLE1 being shown even with left join?
>   How can I make them appear?

That's because you're telling your query to only bring back ATABLE.column1.  If you take gbn or Jack's queries, just indicate ATABLE1.* (or specifically name each of them) in your SELECT clause:

```
select ATABLE1.*, count(ATABLE2.column1) 
from ATABLE1 Left OUTER JOIN ATABLE2
     on ATABLE1.column1 = atable2.column1 AND atable2.column2 = '1'
GROUP BY ATABLE1.column1;
```

Comment: Interesting, I sure hope the OP isn't confused as to how to list all columns.  On the other hand that is what they asked.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [adding the condition to the join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10880/1396) is to test for `null` in the filter:

```
select ATABLE1.column1, count(ATABLE2.column1) 
    from ATABLE1 Left OUTER JOIN ATABLE2 on ATABLE1.column1 = atable2.column1
    where atable2.column2 is null or atable2.column2 = '1'
    GROUP BY ATABLE1.column1;
```

I prefer this variant but you may consider it less readable:

```
select ATABLE1.column1, count(ATABLE2.column1) 
    from ATABLE1 Left OUTER JOIN ATABLE2 on ATABLE1.column1 = atable2.column1
    where decode(atable2.column2,'1',1,null,1,0)=1
    GROUP BY ATABLE1.column1;
```

The only reason for doing this is if for some reason you can't put the condition in the filter (which is sometimes the case in a more complex query)